# No overload for method `TryParse` takes arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm getting the following error message: `No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments` at `if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text))`. What does it mean? Any idea how can I resolve it?

```
    private void driverNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text))
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        int temp;

        if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text))
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DriverNo = " + driverNo.Text;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid driver no.");
    }
```

Comment: "What does it mean?" - It means that you're calling the method wrong. In this case: with the wrong number of arguments (parameters). You might want to use it like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7.aspx) or better yet, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zf50za27.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your `temp` variable to `int.TryParse`

Change

```
 if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text))
```

To

```
if (int.TryParse(driverNo.Text, out temp)) //since temp is defined just for it (I guess(
```

[`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes atleast two arguments, one the string to be parsed, and the other to hold the parsed value, with `out` keyword. You haven't supplied that in your code.

After successful parsing you will get the parsed value in your `temp` variable.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use as `int.TryParse(driverNo.Text)`

use as below.

```
int newValue;    
if(int.TryParse(driverNo.Text, out newValue))
{
}
```